# Do variable modifications get audited in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I need to investigate how and when a variable value within airflow got modified, and am hoping there are some audit logs that answer this question. The audit logs at https://AIRFLOW_INSTANCE/admin/log/ only pertain to DAGs, there is nothing there pertaining to variable modifications.

Do variable modifications get audited and if so, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Airflow does not have audit logs for Variables modifications.

Comment: As I suspected. Thank you.